# Activate a workflow transition from wizard in OpenERP 7.0

Tags: workflow, signals, odoo, wizard, openerp-7

I've set up a wizard in OpenERP 7.0 that is updating fields correctly and all is working fine. But I would like to send a signal to the workflow from that wizard after user submits information to check if there is any transition to be taken.

My wizard code is the following:

```
from openerp.osv import osv
from openerp.osv import fields
from openerp.tools.translate import _

class ref_generic_request(osv.osv_memory):
    _name='ref.generic.request'

    _columns = {
        'reformulation_info': fields.text('Reformulation instructions', help='Instructions for the requestor justification the reformulation needs'),
            }


    def save_info(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        if 'active_id' in context:
            info=self.browse(cr,uid,ids)[0].reformulation_info
            self.pool.get('generic.request').write(cr,uid,context['active_id'],{'reformulation_info' : info, 'needs_reformulation': 1})
        return {
                'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close',
         }
ref_generic_request()
```

And in this particular case I would like to signal this function in my `generic.request` object:

```
def req_reformulate_request(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    req = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    goto = req[0].state
    if goto:
        self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'goto': goto, 'state': 'req_reformulation', 'needs_reformulation': True} )
    else:
        self.write(cr, uid, ids, {'state': 'req_reformulation', 'needs_reformulation': True})
    self.insert_trace(cr, uid, ids, context)
    return True
```

How should I do that?

Do I have to call the function inside the `def save_info()`? (I've tried this call `self.pool.get('generic.request').req_reformulate_request(cr, uid, context['active_id'], context)` but it throws so many errors, that I quickly gave up this approach)

Do I have to return something like `'signal': 'generic.request.req_reformulate_request'` ?
Since I didn't find any information on this, I'm completely lost here, so any help would be very appreciated!

Thanks!

Here is the workflow definition:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record model="workflow" id="wkf_request">
            <field name="name">request.wkf</field>
            <field name="osv">generic.request</field>
            <field name="on_create">True</field>
        </record>

        <!-- actividades -->
        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_draft">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_request" />
            <field name="flow_start">True</field>
            <field name="name">request_draft</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">request_draft()</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_submit">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_request" />
            <field name="name">request_submitted</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">submit_request()</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_confirm">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_request" />
            <field name="name">request_confirmed</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">confirm_request()</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_closed_nconf">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_request" />
            <field name="name">request_closed_nconf</field>
            <field name="action_id" ref="ir_actions_server_send_email_when_closed_nconf"/>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">close_nconf_request()</field>
            <field name="flow_stop">True</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_req_reformulate">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_request" />
            <field name="name">request_reformulation</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">req_reformulate_request()</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_treatment">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_request" />
            <field name="name">request_treatment</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">treat_request()</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_taken">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_request" />
            <field name="name">request_take</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">take_request()</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_given">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_request" />
            <field name="name">request_give</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">give_request()</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_closed">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_request" />
            <field name="name">request_closed</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">close_request()</field>
            <field name="flow_stop">True</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_awaiting_auth">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_request" />
            <field name="name">request_awaiting_authorization</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">wait_auth_request()</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_closed_ref">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_request" />
            <field name="name">request_closed_ref</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">close_ref_request()</field>
            <field name="flow_stop">True</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_awaiting_appr">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_request" />
            <field name="name">request_awainting_approval</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">wait_appr_request()</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.activity" id="act_closed_disappr">
            <field name="wkf_id" ref="wkf_request" />
            <field name="name">request_closed_disappr</field>
            <field name="kind">function</field>
            <field name="action">close_disappr_request()</field>
            <field name="flow_stop">True</field>
        </record>
        <!-- transições -->
        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t1">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_draft" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_submit" />
            <field name="signal">submit_request</field>
        </record>
        <!--
        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t101">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_draft" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_confirm" />
            <field name="signal">submit_request</field>
            <field name="condition">check_responsible()</field>
        </record>
        -->

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t102">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_submit" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_confirm" />
            <field name="condition">check_responsible()</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t2">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_submit" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_req_reformulate" />
            <field name="signal">req_reformulate_request</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t3">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_req_reformulate" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_submit" />
            <field name="signal">submit_request</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t1001">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_submit" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_confirm" />
            <field name="condition">ref_goto_confirmed()</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t1002">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_submit" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_treatment" />
            <field name="condition">ref_goto_treatment()</field>
        </record>


        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t4">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_submit" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_confirm" />
            <field name="signal">confirm_request</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t5">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_submit" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_closed_nconf" />
            <field name="signal">close_nconf_request</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t6">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_confirm" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_treatment" />
            <field name="signal">treat_request</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t7">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_treatment" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_closed" />
            <field name="signal">close_request</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t7011">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_treatment" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_taken" />
            <field name="signal">take_request</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t7012">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_taken" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_treatment" />
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t7021">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_treatment" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_given" />
            <field name="signal">give_request</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t7022">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_given" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_treatment" />
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t8">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_treatment" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_awaiting_auth" />
            <field name="signal">wait_auth_request</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t9">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_awaiting_auth" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_closed_ref" />
            <field name="signal">close_ref_request</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t10">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_awaiting_auth" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_treatment" />
            <field name="signal">auth_send_processing</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t11">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_treatment" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_req_reformulate" />
            <field name="signal">req_reformulate_request</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t12">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_treatment" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_awaiting_appr" />
            <field name="signal">wait_appr_request</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t13">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_awaiting_appr" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_closed_disappr" />
            <field name="signal">close_disappr_request</field>
        </record>

        <record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t14">
            <field name="act_from" ref="act_awaiting_appr" />
            <field name="act_to" ref="act_treatment" />
            <field name="signal">appr_send_processing</field>
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

The transition I want to trigger in this particular case is the one with id="request_t2"

```
<record model="workflow.transition" id="request_t2">
    <field name="act_from" ref="act_submit" />
    <field name="act_to" ref="act_req_reformulate" />
    <field name="signal">req_reformulate_request</field>
</record>
```

And here is a screenshot of the workflow, the highlighted transition is the one I want to trigger.
[image]

Comment: Do you use real workflow (activities, transations, ...)? if so, pls provide us the xml code for the workflow :-)

Comment: Hi, I just added the worfklow definition. And pointed the transition I want to signal.  Thanks! (I'll make also a print of the workflow and add it)

Comment: Just added screenshot of the workflow

Comment: ah ok thx, and i meant transitions not transations ^^

Comment: Just got it to work with the help from an user of the OpenERP comunity. Thanks for your time anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly found the answer. I'll leave here the modified python code that made it!

```
from openerp.osv import osv
from openerp.osv import fields
from openerp.tools.translate import _
import netsvc

class ref_generic_request(osv.osv_memory):
    _name='ref.generic.request'

    _columns = {
        'reformulation_info': fields.text('Reformulation instructions', help='Instructions for the requestor justification the reformulation needs'),
            }


    def save_info(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
        if 'active_id' in context:
            info=self.browse(cr,uid,ids)[0].reformulation_info
            self.pool.get('generic.request').write(cr,uid,context['active_id'],{'reformulation_info' : info, 'needs_reformulation': 1})
            wf_service = netsvc.LocalService('workflow')
            wf_service.trg_validate(uid,'generic.request',context['active_id'],'req_reformulate_request',cr)    
        return {
                'type': 'ir.actions.act_window_close',

         }

ref_generic_request()
```

So, resuming, I had to add 3 lines to my code:
`import netsvc`

And, after saving my info, invoked the workflow with these two:

```
wf_service = netsvc.LocalService('workflow')
wf_service.trg_validate(uid,'generic.request',context['active_id'],'req_reformulate_request',cr)
```

Hope this will help someone! :)

Comment: seems right, now i see that you're using a transient model with name ref.generic.model, so my answer wasn't alĺ right. i have deleted it, yours is more than enough :-)

Answer (score 0):

On `odoo8` use `signal_workflow` method.

```
@api.multi
def confirm_multi_payslips(self):
    for payslip in self:
        payslip.signal_workflow('hr_verify_sheet')
```